# how to make curl available in my container in k8s pod?

Tags: kubernetes, curl, networking

I'm using busybox image in my pod. I'm trying to curl another pod, but "curl is not found". How to fix it?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: front
  name: front
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: front
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - sleep 1d
```

this cmd:

```
k exec -it front -- sh
curl service-anotherpod:80 -> 'curl not found'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to @gohm'c's answer, you could also try uusing Alpine Linux and either make your own image that has curl installed, or use `apk add curl` in the pod to install it.

Example pod with alpine:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: front
  name: front
spec:
  containers:
  - image: alpine
    name: front
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - sleep 1d
```

Comment: thx but how to install it inside? you mean just k exec into the container and do it manually? or inside initcontainers?

Comment: You can `exec` into the pod and install it manually using `apk install curl` if it's only a temporary need (for example, if you are debugging something), or you can make your own docker image based on alpine, install curl within there, then refer to that in the pod. It's up to you.

Comment: @BlenderFox I get error `bash: apk: command not found`

Comment: @likejudo `apk` is an alpine linux specific tool, if you're using a different image, it won't work, you would need to use whatever package manager is for that image (dnf, yum, apt-get, pacman, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

`busybox` is a single binary program which you can't install additional program to it. You can either use `wget` or you can use a different variant of busybox like [progrium](https://github.com/progrium/busybox) which come with a package manager that allows you to do `opkg-install curl`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own image and deploy it to a pod.  Here is an example Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache \
        bind-tools \
        curl \
        iproute2 \
        wget \
        && \
        : 
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" , "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

Which you can then build like this

```
docker image build -t networkutils:latest  .
```

Run like this

`docker container run -rm -d --name networkutils networkutils`

And access it's shell to run curl, wget, or whichever commands you have installed like this

`docker container exec -it networkutils sh`

To run and access it in k3s you can do make a deployment file like this

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: networkutils
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: networkutils
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: networkutils
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: networkutils
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: networkutils-container
        image: networkutils:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Start the pod
`kubectl apply -f deployment.yml`

And then access the shell
`kubectl exec -it networkutils -- /bin/sh`